# Ratio-of-averages vs average-of-ratios with "implicit weight"

Tags: descriptive-statistics, mean, precision-recall

I have some precision/recall data for an algorithm, run against multiple inputs $i$, where:

$\text{precision}_i = \frac{\text{matches}_i}{\text{generated}_i}$

$\text{recall}_i = \frac{\text{matches}_i}{\text{possible}_i}$

Where $i$ is a particular test input, and for each input we have an associated "desired"/ground-truth output. $\text{possible}_i$ is the size of the "desired" output set for input $i$, $\text{generated}_i$ is the size of the actual output the algorithm gave for input $i$, and $\text{matches}_i$ is how many elements of the actual output match elements of the "desired" output.

There are two ways to average these: the average of the ratios:

$\text{precision}_A = \frac{\sum_i{\text{precision}_i}}{i}$

Or the ratio of the averages:

$\text{precision}_B = \frac{\sum_i{\text{matches}_i}}{\sum_i{\text{generated}_i}}$

The important thing to consider is that the sizes $\text{possible}_i$ may vary a lot, so we may get precisions like $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{10}{20}$. To predict how it will perform against unknown inputs, latter seems to "carry more weight" than the former, since it's based on larger data sets, which makes me think that the ratio of the averages is the most appropriate. Does this seem reasonable?

What would be an appropriate error to give these values? The variance or standard deviation seems to make more sense with regards to the average of the ratios, rather than the ratio of averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to someone about this, we decided that the average of the ratios (i.e. the mean) is a better statistic in this case.

The problem domain is discovering mathematical theorems. Our reasoning is that some inputs have higher absolute numbers because they're "more amenable" to stating theorems. As an example, it's easy to state lots of theorems about the `plus` function; it's not so easy to state theorems about the `Riemann zeta` function.

However, we would *not* be justified in saying that "more amenable" inputs are *better* than "less amenable" ones. Our intention is to quantify the performance of mathematical search algorithms, *not* to make philosophical claims about what things are "mathematically better" than others. Hence there is no justification to the weighting that a ratio of the averages would imply, so we should use the average of the ratios since it treats all inputs equally (a good "default" position to take, in lieu of such justifications).